# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss JBOSS eap 7.2 JAVA

Tags: java, jms, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to connect JMS queue on JBoss EAP 7.2 using Java. My code to get the initial context is below:

```java
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jms123");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jms123");
return new InitialContext(env);
```

And after getting the `InitialContext` I'm trying to get the connection factory as below:

```java
qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

But I'm not able to get the connection factory.

Note: I tried using `jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` and `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` as well.

I am getting the below exception:

```
NamingException caught while trying to create connection:javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: 
  Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory from classloader 
  ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.***.jar" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory from [Module " 
 deployment.***.jar" from Service Module Loader]];jsessionid=MwSDukhCPIR813I4R8-GWocZZgzVy-srp6eCb-If
   FatalException: Trouble opening session with JMS Sender instance:FatalException: Could not get 
  connection to Queue

    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss
```

My xml config is below:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <journal pool-files="10"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="MailJMSServer" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/ConcurrentBEQueue"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Please help me find out the root cause.

Comment: I can now create queueConnectionFactory with below Initial context config                                                    
    `// Init initial context
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jms123");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jms123");`

Comment: Why were there references to WebLogic classes in your error message?

Comment: Also, if you found the root issue please it in an actual answer and then mark the answer as correct.